# Finding the full path of a directory if it exists and store in a variable using bash script

Tags: bash

I want to find the full path of a particular directory and store the path in a variable using a bash script.
For eg, I want to search "ruby/lib".Its full path is "/usr/share/ruby/lib" and I want to capture this path in a variable for further processes.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `find` you could say:

```
find / -type d -path "*/ruby/lib"
```

In order to capture the results into a variable, say:

```
out=$(find / -type d -path "*/ruby/lib")
```

Comment: `find` sounds good as it is installed on every system (in opposite to `realpath` which has to be installed first)

Comment: It worked!! Thanks.But it seems to be slow somewhat.

Comment: @NagaLakshmi It's slow because you're searching in the root directory.  If you're sure that it'd exist in, say `/usr`, then you could say `find /usr -type d -path "*/ruby/lib"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

(Thanks to @dstronczak), I would use `readlink` for it. Its:

```
path=$(readlink -f ruby/lib)
```

Note that there MUST be no space between `path` and the `=`

Comment: Welcome :) Back in the day I got really used to `realpath` on my ubuntu machine. Now I tend to use the alias: `alias realpath='readlink -f'` ;)